# Automated Testing with Javascript for any web app - need more suggestions and ideas

Tags: javascript, web-applications, automated-tests, autotest

**BACKGROUND:** I've been looking for **auto-testing tools** for my web-app developed in C# having AJAX. I tried to find some tools but some were complex, some were paid and some would not allow me to tweak in. Some are listed below but I wanted something on which I had the total control and would be v.light weight and easily portable.

My inspirations :)

- http://watin.sourceforge.net
- http://sahi.co.in/w/
- http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

**SOLUTION:** So, finally getting back to my old javascript skills I ended up creating my own simple (and hopefully effective) auto-testing tool! The idea was to create a wrapper parent html page which will 'host' the web-page to be tested in an iframe and then access its controls, populate value and perform clicks, etc...

> *NOTE: Both the pages need to be on the same machine to be tested (cross
>   domain testing is not allowed)

Here's a sample image explaining my method -
[image: Auto-testing form for Login page]

> And here's the wrapper page
>   **code** : http://www.codeupload.com/3813

I'd like to know your suggestions and idea about the same and what you prefer. I see many usage of this method like - auto-testing, showing an automated demo, automated-data-entry,... but everything on the same domain.

Here's my **codeproject article**:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/JS-Automated-Testing.aspx

*Please share your thoughts. And  if some one is interested I've also posted a **youtube** video showing it live in action:* 
**http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_z_IrFztBo**

Thank you

PS: Hope this is not misleading, I'm not advertising, its just for sharing and learning ;)

Comment: In addition I also realize that most of the testing IDEs have a time-based postback handling (i.e. like wait for 30 seconds) where as my pure javascript based approach isn't bound to this - it can wait forever until the postback returns!

Comment: One more thing I forgot - its best to handle AJAX based postback and other tricky coding that many web developers do to make a feature rich GUI.